# File check in C Language

Tags: c

I need to ask you about a better way to check if a file exists or not, because i really do not know which is the right way.
i have a program which works just fine, but the problem appears when i have to deal with different kind of files, not just, lets say `txt` files.
I am a Linux user and i tried to see how the program works if i try to use it on a Library file.

Here is the problem, the program cannot read that file because i use READ MODE  `"r"`, and the library file is not a `txt` file.
How can i check if that file exist ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
    FILE * fp;
    char *fileNAme = "secret.txt";
    size_t fileLong;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    /*Check if the file exists, if not Exit*/
    fp = fopen (fileNAme , "r");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tThe file %s does not Exists\n\n\n\n\n", fileNAme);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the Number of Chars present and store them in FileLong*/
    fseek (fp , 0 , SEEK_END);
    fileLong = (size_t)ftell (fp);

    /* Print the size of the FileLong */
    if(fileLong == 0){
        printf("The Size of the File is \t= %ld\n",fileLong);
    }else{
        printf("The Size of the File is \t= %ld\n",fileLong-1);
    }

    /* Moving the pointer back to the begining of the file */
    rewind (fp);

    /* allocate memory to the buffer to which is needed for holding the whole File content */
    buffer = malloc (sizeof(char)*fileLong);

    /* Check if the memory was aloccated, if not print the Error and Exit */
    if (buffer == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }

    /* copy the file into the buffer:*/
    result = fread (buffer,1,fileLong,fp);

    /*Print the size of the Buffer*/
    if(result == 0){
        printf("The size of the Buffer is \t= %ld\n",result);
    }else{
        printf("The size of the Buffer is \t= %ld\n",result-1);
    }

    /* Check if the Buffer have the same size as lsize */
    if (result != fileLong){
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit (1);
    }else{
        printf("\nThe Content of the File(%ld)\tis the same as the content of the Buffer(%ld)\n", fileLong-1, result-1);
    }

    /* Now we can print the Content of the File */
    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\tThe Content of the File is:\n");

    /* Compare result with FileLong to see if there are some information inside that File or not */
    if(result != 0 && fileLong != 0){
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }else{
        printf("\n\n\nThe File is empty\n\n\n");
    }

    /* Close that File */
    fclose (fp);

    /* Free the needed memory*/
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You might not be able to open a file because you don't have permissions or it's already in use, but it should not matter what type of file it is.  Reading data out of it is another matter, but you should be able to open any type of file using `fopen`.

Comment: In am 100% sure you are right, i know that i have no permission on that file. My problem is, how can i check its existence, please tell me. Thank you

Comment: One bad thing about the `fopen` approach is that opening a large file will cause a hitch, so if you can't afford "lagging", you may want a platform specific solution (probably `stat` in Linux).

Comment: Is there no way in C to check if a file exists, no mather which kind of file or which kind of permission haves ? just to check it ? I mean one Function for both OS (windows and Linux) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post a part of my solution.

It is a Linux work out, because I'm not a Windows User and for my needs it is enough to check if a file exists in C using `access`.

Here is the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void fileCheck(const char *fileName){

    if(!access(fileName, F_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t was Found\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t not Found\n",fileName);
    }

    if(!access(fileName, R_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t can be readed\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t cannot be readed\n",fileName);
    }

    if(!access( fileName, W_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t it can be Edited\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t it cannot be Edited\n",fileName);
    }

    if(!access( fileName, X_OK )){
        printf("The File %s\t is an Executable\n",fileName);
    }else{
        printf("The File %s\t is not an Executable\n",fileName);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    char *fileName = "/boot/grub/grub.cfg";

    fileCheck(fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> The File /boot/grub/grub.cfg     was Found
> The File /boot/grub/grub.cfg     can be readed
> The File /boot/grub/grub.cfg     it cannot be Edited
> The File /boot/grub/grub.cfg     is not an Executable
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`access()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) API with `F_OK` to check the existence of the file.

You need to include the header file `unistd.h`.

FWIW, you can also use `R_OK`, `W_OK`, and `X_OK` to check whether the file got read, write and execute permission, additionally.

Here is how you could use `access`:

```
if( !access( filename, F_OK )) 
{
    // file is present
}
else 
{
    // file is not there
}
```

Comment: I tried those changes and its not working. 
The file libdns.so.100 was not Found.

But the file is there

Comment: @Michi what is not working? did you provide the _full path_ to the file?

Comment: The file is there where the executable program find, in the same folder.
Can you please modify my program (whole) to understand those changes. Thank you

Comment: @Michi can you please check `errno` for possible failure?

Comment: Errno says:
`Value of errno: 2
Error opening the file: No such file or directory
Error printed by perror: No such file or directory` But the file is there, secret.txt is readed, this one not :|

Comment: You said somewhere you have no permission to that file. Do you have permission to see it (permissions on the containing directories)? Can the user running the program access the file e.g. by `file /path/to/file/libdns.so.100` in the console?

Comment: The file is inside of my Home Folder, so i do have permissions.  My problem is, how do i can check a file for existens in C language. Is not important which kind of file or which kind of permisssions have that file. Something which you can do in bash like, "if [ -f /tmp/foo.txt ]"

Comment: This is What is get: `michi@michi ~/Documents/Sensors/Sensors $ ls * libdns.so.100 
.
So the File is There,but:
michi@michi ~/Documents/Sensors/Sensors $ cat libdns.so.100 
cat: libdns.so.100: No such file or directory
michi@michi ~/Documents/Sensors/Sensors $ sudo cat libdns.so.100 
cat: libdns.so.100: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter what type of file it is, `fopen` will still return a valid `FILE` pointer if it can be opened. So one easy way is simply to use `fopen` and see if it returns `NULL` or not.

Another, more Linux (or rather POSIX) way may be to use the [`access`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) function, or possibly the [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) function.